# php output in alphabetical order after explode

Tags: php

i have a string like

```
 $email= "yun@hotmail.com,sibel@hotmail.com,yusufsar@hotmail.com";
```

first i explode this like

```
 $wordChunks = explode(",", $email);
for($i = 0; $i < count($wordChunks); $i++){

$eex = mysqli_query($database->connection,"SELECT * FROM contacts where email =   '$wordChunks[$i]' and owner = '$session->username'") or die(mysqli_error());
    while($zzz = mysqli_fetch_array($eex)){


     if(empty($zzz['bedrijfsnaam'])){
        $aa = "<font size='2'>".ucfirst($zzz['name'])." ".ucfirst($zzz['lastname'])."</font>";
    }else{
     $aa = "<font size='2'>".ucfirst($zzz['bedrijfsnaam'])."</font>";
    }
    echo $aa;

     }
}
```

The question is how can i order $aa in alphabetic order

What i tried is

```
$array = str_split($aa, 1);
sort($array);
foreach ($array as $val) {
echo $val."<br>";
}
```

But this orders only the string in $aa; example 
string = hellow
output is ehllow. but i want order the output of $aa in the while loop

Comment: You can ORDER BY in your SQL statement, if I understand you right.

Comment: Order is not needed becouse the db output is a single output per email

Comment: did you find how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

No need to use explode()  and than loop it. Just put that string in query and it will work.Change your query to use IN() for searching emails and do order by so that you will get the data in ascending order itself.
you can try like this:

```
$eex = mysqli_query($database->connection,"SELECT * FROM contacts where email IN ($email) and owner = '$session->username' order by email") or die(mysqli_error());
    while($zzz = mysqli_fetch_array($eex)){


     if(empty($zzz['bedrijfsnaam'])){
        $aa = "<font size='2'>".ucfirst($zzz['name'])." ".ucfirst($zzz['lastname'])."</font>";
    }else{
     $aa = "<font size='2'>".ucfirst($zzz['bedrijfsnaam'])."</font>";
    }
    echo $aa;

     }
```

Comment: This is not the answer what i am looking for. I must explode $email and use it to get the results in db for each email that is exploded. Each email adresses in $email is also in contacts row of my db with information what i need like name lastname...

Answer (score 0):

**Just Use**

```
$aa = 'hellow';
$array = str_split($aa, 1);

foreach ($array as $val) {
echo $val."<br>";
}
```

Result:

h
e
l
l
o
w